# Ajax call in laravel - append data in div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm new in Laravel world but I need to understand and make clear to myself basic stuffs. So I have one problem. I want to make ajax call to controller and return & print data in existing div element in view. View is rendered by another controller. Basicly, I want to show loading circle while user waiting for load data. This is code:

routes.php

```
Route::get('/members', "MembersController@index");
Route::get('/members/show/{provider}', 'AjaxController@main');
```

AjaxController.php

```
class AjaxController extends BaseController
{
    public function main($provider)
    {
        if($provider == 'test')
        {
            return "this is test";
        }

    }
}
```

In view I have one link to call ajax, and one empty div. Ajax call work great, but insted to show "This is test" in div in view rendered from MembersController, laravel opens new page with url "www.domain.com/members/show/test" and then print "this is test". I dont want that, I just want to load return date directly in div. How can I fix that?

Comment: We need to see the JS to be sure but I'm betting the issue is on the JavaScript side. Laravel only returns data, it's the client that decides to open a new window or redirect the page.

Answer (score 1):

You better return a HTTP `Response()`:

```
class AjaxController extends BaseController
{
    public function main($provider)
    {
        if($provider == 'test')
        {
            return Response::json(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'this is test'));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using link to invoke AJAX call, I think you have not switched off the default behavoir of the link.

Typically I would tackle this problem like this using JQuery.

```
$('#element-to-invoke-ajax').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
         url : 'members/show/test',
         ....
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, but now it's working without any change. Maybe my IDE didn't upload all files because I develop on remote server...Wired :) But thanks guys :)